# Converting a Context-Free Grammar to a PDA

Tags: theory, context-free-grammar, automata, pushdown-automaton, automata-theory

I am attempting to convert the following CFG to a pushdown automaton:

```
S → AS | A
A → 0A | 1B | 1
B → 0B | 0
```

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, or the problem of CFG->PDA in general.

Comment: sounds like a homework. maybe try to review the textbook first?

Comment: As a hint, the language of this grammar is regular, so you could build a finite automaton for it and then easily convert that to a PDA.

Comment: It was an online homework problem I couldn't get, and the online explanation didn't give me much help. I was hoping someone could explain it.

Comment: @Dan9993 [CFG to PDA Example](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/Classes/Archives/cps360.98spring/Examples/CFGtoPDA/tsld001.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Conversation of Context free grammar to Pushdown automata:
Steps to convert CFG to Pushdown automata:
Step-1:The first symbol on R.H.S. production must be a terminal symbol.

Step-2:Convert the given productions of CFG into GNF.

Step-3:The PDA will only have one state {q}.

Step-4:The initial symbol of CFG will be the initial symbol in the PDA.

Step-5:For non-terminal symbol, add the following rule:
δ(q, ε, A) = (q, α)
Where the production rule is A → α.

Step-6:For each terminal symbols, add the following rule:
δ(q, a, a) = (q, ε) for every terminal symbol

Answer (score 0):

You may use JFlap application to do it for you.
http://www.jflap.org/
Beyond this there are several other interesting functionalyties in that application that will help you study formal languages.
I've been using it for about two weeks and I'm loving it.